# Issue in passing Loop values to Ansible Debug message

Tags: ansible

I am trying to print the file names in a path using ansible debug module with help of loop iteration. But facing error for with_sequence loop.

PFB the Playbook,

```
---

- name: Find Module Playbook
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
        - name: Find files in tmp path.
          find:
                paths: /tmp
                patterns: "*.txt"
                recurse: yes

          register: files_match

        - name: No of Files found.
          debug:
                 msg: "Number of files matched is {{ files_match.matched }}"
#                msg: [ 
#                     "Number of files matched is {{ files_match.matched }}",
#                     "Files matching the patterns are {{ files_match.files[ item ].path }}"
#                     ]

        - name: Files Found.
#          debug:
#                 msg: "Files matching the patterns are {{ files_match.files[ item ].path }}"

          command: echo "{{ item }}"


#          with_sequence: start=0 end={{ files_match.matched }}

#          with_sequence: start=0 end={{ files_match.matched|int }}

          with_items:
                - 0
                - 1
                - 2
                - 3
                - 4
                - 5
```

Error Message:

> TASK [Files Found.]
>   ********************************************************************************************************************************** fatal: [13.250.101.163]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an
>   option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no
>   attribute u'0'\n\nThe error appears to have been in
>   '/home/ansible_admin/Ansible_Playbooks/Find.yml': line 24, column 11,
>   but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
>   problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n        - name:
>   Files Found.\n          ^ here\n"}    to retry, use: --limit
>   @/home/ansible_admin/Ansible_Playbooks/Find.retry
>
> PLAY RECAP
>
> ---
>
> 13.250.101.163: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Actually all the three loops used in the playbook works perfectly same for "command:" where as only the with_items loop is working with "debug: msg". I tried most possible ways but the issue still persists. Are there any corrections to be made here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integer conversion is not in the correct place. It should be:

`{{ files_match.files[ item | int ].path }}`

Comment: The suggested solution worked perfectly. From this I could understand that the 'item' value from 'with_sequence' may not be integer and still needs a type conversion before usage. So what is the output 'item' type from 'with_sequence' loop. Suggest if there are corrections needed in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Also found an alternate solution for the above question which was actually not using the looping at all. Try the below debug msg without any loops,

msg: "Files matching the patterns are {{ files_match.files|map(attribute='path') | list }}"

But for a perfect solution use the previous suggestion.